# Adding to iterator while within current "while (iterator.hasNext())" loop

Tags: java

In the below code, I would expect the iteration to be run 3 times. At first, the iterator has 1 "next", but during the first iteration two more values are added to the iterator, so there should be two more "next" i.e. `iterator.hasNext()` should be true.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("A");
        ListIterator<String> iterator = strings.listIterator();
        int i = 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            i++;
            String str = iterator.next();
            if (str.equals("A")) {
                iterator.add("B");
                iterator.add("C");
            }
          //  strings.remove(str);
          //  iterator = strings.listIterator();
        }
        System.out.println("The iteration was run " + i + " times");
    }
}
```

But it only runs once. As a workaround I can remove the current iteration from the original list, and then reset the iterator (commented lines). But why is this necessary? Shouldn't the iterator already know that it has more values to iterate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't the iterator already know that it has more values to iterate?

No, it shouldn't. If you look into the documentation for `add()` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add-E-) then you can find a following sentence there

> a subsequent call to next would be unaffected, and a subsequent call to previous would return the new element. (This call increases by one the value that would be returned by a call to nextIndex or previousIndex.)

It makes it clear that adding a new element won't affect your current loop flow. Also, if you look into the source code of `ListIterator` implementation for `ArrayList`:

```
...
public E next() {
    checkForComodification();
    int i = cursor;
    if (i >= SubList.this.size)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
    if (offset + i >= elementData.length)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    cursor = i + 1;
    return (E) elementData[offset + (lastRet = i)];
}

public void add(E e) {
    checkForComodification();

    try {
        int i = cursor;
        SubList.this.add(i, e);
        cursor = i + 1;
        lastRet = -1;
        expectedModCount = ArrayList.this.modCount;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
}
```

`cursor` variable points to a position that is used by `next()` to return a next element. As you can see, both `cursor` and `SubList` size get incremented. So, actually, `cursor` is adjusted to skip the "old" next position in favor of the "new" next position. Each time `add()` is called, `cursor` gets adjusted accordingly. To get new elements you should either use `previous()` or start the loop over again.

Additionally, your case can be illustrated as below:

```
    cursor
      |
      V 
0     1
A
```

After `B` and `C` are added, `cursor` still points to a non-existent element:

```
    cursor
      |
      V 
0 1 2 3
A B C
```